# Unable to getElementById() after inserting HTML from a file using innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I have a quiz app with a series of questions implemented as a slide-deck. The deck is played in a single-page application (SPA). I have the HTML for each slide in a folder and it is loaded into a div container in the index.html file that is the single entry-point.

I use the id of the placeholder div tag in index.html and the `innerHTML` property to load a slide. The slide is rendered correctly on the page and inspection of the page source shows that the HTML was correctly loaded (i.e. as HTML and not text). However, I am unable to find the HTML elements within the inserted HTML with `getElementById()` in the application's code. It is as if they don't exist.

Here is the code that loads the HTML to display a slide. It runs when `DOMContentLoaded`.

```
    fetch('./Slides/Quiz001.html')
        .then(data => data.text())
        .then(html => document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML = html)
        .then([].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"))
        .forEach(div_element => console.log(div_element.id)));
```

The first line fetches the slide to insert from a local folder. The second line gets the HTML string. The third line inserts the HTML into the page at the DOM insertion point. The fourth line queries all the div elements and converts `HTMLCollection` to array and the fifth line logs the IDs to console.

The HTML in `Quiz001.html` is as follows:

```
<div id="Quiz">
    <h3>Patanjali Yoga Sutra</h3>
    <div id="Expected" data-answer="asmina"></div>
    <p>The five kleshas, the root cause of suffering, are avidya, 
        <input type="text" id="response" data-binding="response">, 
        raga, dvesa and abhinivesa.
    </p>
</div>
```

There are two div elements in here, with id's "Quiz" and "Expected". These do not appear in the list logged to console by the javascript. In fact, after the insertion, I am unable to get any element in the inserted HTML by querying with `getElementById()` or any other method. It is like they are not visible in the code although the HTML is properly inserted and the elements are correctly seen in page source.

[image]

I have added a screenshot of the page and console, and highlighted the HTML that is inserted by javascript. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you check in dev tool if HTML that you are trying to add in 3rd line of function is added as DOM element or text?

Comment: @Dhara Thank you for the suggestion. I have checked the source and the HTML is added correctly as HTML and not as text.

Comment: Just for kicks, I'd try replacing arrow functions with traditional functions, e.g.`.then(function(html) { document.getElementById("Question").innerHTML = html; })`.

Comment: @kmoser I tried your suggestion and replaced arrow functions with regular functions. There is no change. Thanks for giving me something to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.then([].slice.call(document.getElementsByTagName("div"))
```

This line is evaluated immediately, not as part of the Promise chain. You forgot the `()=>` to make it a callback.